# Python - get latest date column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

Problem: I have a pandas DataFrame, that has several columns. Some of the columns are strings as dates for example: `["A", "2019-12-01 00:00:00", "2020-01-01 00:00:00"]`

Q:How does one choose the latest date column in this case, keeping in mind that the column location might be different at some point in time?
In the example case above, the latest date from `["A", "2019-12-01 00:00:00", "2020-01-01 00:00:00"]` would be `"2020-01-01 00:00:00"`

Possible solution: I was thinking of potentially doing a regex search to match the numbers and dashes and find the strings that adhere to the specific datetime format, using something like `date_list = regex.match(columns)` then transform everything to datetime, find the max date by doing `max_date = date_list.max()` and then `df[str(max_date)]`

Q: But maybe there's a sort-of-built-in-way or just-a-better-way to do this than the possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting column names to dates with `pd.to_datetime` and `errors='coerce'` parameter to ignore non-datetime values, and then taking `max`:

```
cols = ["A", "2019-12-01 00:00:00", "2020-01-01 00:00:00"]
pd.to_datetime(cols, errors='coerce').max()
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you! Looks like this was what I was looking for. Let me check if this works on my end :)

Comment: I tried, but I got to wait for 2 more mins :D I will do it, no problem ;)